# Visual Studio Code is not suggesting relative imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, configuration, pylance

For some reason, if I have a variable inside my project, Vscode stopped suggesting imports when i press `Ctrl + Space`.

For example, I have a class in `types.py`:

```
class StepStatus(ExtendedEnum):
    RUNNING = "RUNNING"
    ERROR = "ERROR"
    OK = "OK"
```

At the same level, another file called `runner.py`, but if try to auto import this variable it raises `no suggestions`:
[image]

But if I manually import the `StepStatus` variable it exists:

[image]

There is my vscode `settings.json` content:

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        },
    },
    "isort.args": [
        "--profile",
        "black"
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme High Contrast",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
}
```

I already tried to reinstall Vscode, reinstall Pylance extension, delete cache but nothing works. The auto import suggestions only works for the default libraries such as json, typing, datetime...

Comment: What is the relationship between the code you showed and the picture? Is this an example? At least I can't reproduce it here.

Comment: Sorry, I typed the wrong class in the code. Maybe now is more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, even if I clear all settings and then add the content of your `settings.json`. This is still [achievable on my machine](https://imgur.com/Kbsj6hr). So can you please provide more information? Such as your file structure and what level of folders you open in VS code, etc.

Comment: It happens also with installed libraries. I'm using the default python3 interpreter, it has pandas lib installed but the auto import doesn't works and Pylance extension raises this error:
"pandas" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable). Basically the auto import only works for the default libraries(datetime, typinmg, etc).

Comment: Make sure you are using the same interpreter as the one you installed the `pandas` library with.

Comment: I`m sure about that because if manually import pandas it works, the problem is about Pylance Intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `StepStatus` class in your script, how does IntelliSense prompt?

So I guess you have the following code under your `types.py` script

```py
class StepStatus(ExtendedEnum):
    RUNNING = "RUNNING"
    ERROR = "ERROR"
    OK = "OK"
```

Then intellisense will be provided when you type `StepStatus` in the `runner.py` script in the same directory:

[image]

Enter or select, it will be imported automatically

[image]

Type `.` and smart suggestions also work

[image]

Comment: Thats my problem, my Intellisense doesn't suggests the autoimport as your first picture.

Comment: What does your workspace look like? Try installing a pre-release version of the python extension?